# How to convert time in Indian region in firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hello I know this is a very normal question but I did not find the solution since 3 hours .
My firebase time is set to us central . I want the current Indian time

this is my code

```
var formatedTime = new Date().getHours() + ':' + new Date().getMinutes();
```

It is giving me server time . How to convert it to Indian region current Time

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone for a good explanation of JavaScript dates and timezones.

Answer (score 1):

You should maintain the new Date() as it is in UTC. Instead, use toLocaleString for India specific time:

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"})
```

or

```
new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"})
```